# Angular JSON browserTarget is deprectaed

Tags: angular

borwserTarget show deprecated in my angular json file and if am using builtarget instaed of browserTarget then  Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.this warning is show, how can i fix this,i am new in angular ,if anyone know, please let me know

[angular Json screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P54cB.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Angular veersion and make sure it is up-to-date.

In your `angular.json` ... `buildTarget`:

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "buildTarget": "Flight:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js",
      "buildTarget": "Flight:build:development"
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```